# Why do Windows and Linux have different strdup implementations: strdup() and _strdup()?

Tags: c, cross-platform, posix

When working with `strdup` on Windows I found out that `_strdup` is Windows specific, but when I ran the same code on Linux it required `strdup` without the underscore. Does anyone know the history behind this difference, as-well as some information on how you have dealt with this problem when writing cross-platform code?

Comment: `strdup()` is not a standard C function, it comes from POSIX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several functions that are part of the POSIX specification, i.e. Linux and most other UNIX variants, that are not part of standard C.  These include `strdup`, `write`, `read`, and others.

The reasoning for the leading underscore is as follows, taken from the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/compatibility?view=vs-2019):

> The Universal C Run-Time Library (UCRT) supports most of the C
>   standard library required for C++ conformance. It implements the C99
>   (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) library, with certain exceptions: The type-generic
>   macros defined in , and strict type compatibility in
>   . **The UCRT also implements a large subset of the POSIX.1
>   (ISO/IEC 9945-1:1996, the POSIX System Application Program Interface)
>   C library. However, it's not fully conformant to any specific POSIX
>   standard.** The UCRT also implements several Microsoft-specific
>   functions and macros that aren't part of a standard.
>
> Functions specific to the Microsoft implementation of Visual C++ are
>   found in the vcruntime library. Many of these functions are for
>   internal use and can't be called by user code. Some are documented for
>   use in debugging and implementation compatibility.
>
> **The C++ standard reserves names that begin with an underscore in the
>   global namespace to the implementation. Both the POSIX functions and
>   Microsoft-specific runtime library functions are in the global
>   namespace, but aren't part of the standard C runtime library. That's
>   why the preferred Microsoft implementations of these functions have a
>   leading underscore.** For portability, the UCRT also supports the
>   default names, but the Microsoft C++ compiler issues a deprecation
>   warning when code that uses them is compiled. Only the default names
>   are deprecated, not the functions themselves. To suppress the warning,
>   define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS before including any headers in code
>   that uses the original POSIX names.

I've handled that by having a `#define` that check if the program is being compiled for Windows, and if so create another `#define` to map the POSIX name to the Windows specific name.  There are a few choices you can check, although probably the most reliable is `_MSC_VER` which is defined if MSVC is the compiler.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define strdup(p) _strdup(p)
#endif
```